# Password Confirmation error not displayed in django forms

Tags: django, sqlite

I tried to compare password and confirmpassword. If i enter different password it does not raise error and redirects to loginpage.

models.py

```py
class reg1(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cpassword=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table='reg1'
```

forms.py

```py
class regform(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    cpassword=forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    def clean_password(self):
        if self.data['password'] != self.data['cpassword']:
            raise forms.Error('Passwords are not the same')
        return self.data['password']
```

views.py

```py
if myregform.is_valid():
    name1 = myregform.cleaned_data['name']
    city1 = myregform.cleaned_data['city']
    email = myregform.cleaned_data['email']
    username1 = myregform.cleaned_data['username']
    password1 = myregform.cleaned_data['password']
    password2=myregform.cleaned_data['cpassword']
    a=reg1(name=name1,city=city1,email=email,
         username=username1,password=password1,cpassword=password2)
    a.save()
```

I expect the output as i enter a different password it will show password not matching error

I am using pycharm software and django framework with sqlite3 database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a ModelForm to save yourself a bunch of typing.
2. You need to use `clean()` to validate data that relates to other fields.
3. You need to raise `ValidationErrors`.

```py
class reg1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cpassword = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "reg1"


class regform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = reg1
        exclude = ()

    def clean(self, cleaned_data):
        if cleaned_data["password"] != cleaned_data["cpassword"]:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords are not the same")
        return cleaned_data


# ...

if myregform.is_valid():
    a = myregform.save()
```